# Reading boolean variables into Mysql from csv

Tags: mysql, csv, boolean

What is the secret of reading boolean values from a csv into a mysql database? I set up the columns as "tinyint(1)" however, when I try to read the csv into the database, it only reads in "0" I've tried adjusting the output of the program writing the csv so it has been both "true/false" and "0/1" neither works. It simply is not reading in any of the values it's being provided.

Below is the command I'm using to read in the csv into mysql

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user1/Programs/csv/info.csv' INTO TABLE infodb FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Below is my Mysql table:

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | int           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name               | varchar(15)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| trail              | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| owner              | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| decision           | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| path               | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

id and name go in fine, but trail, owner, decision, path only show up as false

CSV has been formatted in two ways, first:

```
234 James, 0, 1, 1, 0
222, John, 1, 0, 1, 0
522, Tony, 1, 1, 1, 0
```

Then I also tried:

```
234, James, false, true, true, false
222, John, true, false, true, false
522, Tony, true, true, true, false
```

Neither works

Comment: Please provide `info.csv` data.

Comment: 234, James, 0, 1, 1, 0
421, John, 1, 0, 1, 0

Comment: Have you tried defining the column list?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html Could be running into `You must also specify a column list if the order of the fields in the input file differs from the order of the columns in the table`.

Comment: No I've adjusted the order of the columns to match the order of the fields in the input file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the field as Boolean?
What does the csv look like?
name,active,etc
where 'active' is a numeric one or zero?

Comment: I actually declared it as boolean (eg trail boolean) and it automatically set it to tinyint(1)

Comment: csv  has looked like: 
    234, James, 0, 1, 1, 0 as well as: 
    234, James, true, false, true, true, false

Comment: Consider creating a test table named tbl_test with only two columns/fields...

Comment: Consider creating a test table named tbl_test with only two columns/fields...
fld_name, fld_status... and set fld_name type to varchar or text... and set fld_status type to boolean. Now create a csv file using a text editor like NotePad or NotePad++ with two items per row... separated by a comma... Example: Joe,1 Mary,1 Elvis,0 ... put a carrage return after each row... no comma after the number, just between the name and the number. Now you have created a simple csv file. try to import that into tbl_test. At least this will give you a simple test platform.